# Calculating Cumulative decrease in a pandas time series

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Trying to calculate the cumulative decrease in a time series:

Example:

```
time = ['00:00','00:01','00:03','00:05','00:06','00:10']
data = [100,50,60,50,80,100]
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':time,'C':data})
```

The function should calculate 60 points drop but I only get 50 with the following method:

```
C = 'C'
# Calculate when c drops (added 1000 to see first value)
c_drop = df[C] <= df[C].shift().fillna(100000)
# Get the value drop timestamps
c = df[ c_drop ][C]
# Calculate difference  ΔC
ΔC = (c.shift() - c).fillna(0)
# Sum only the positive ΔC
result = sum(ΔC[ΔC>0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating it a bit, this should do the trick:

```
-df['C'].diff().clip(None,0).sum()
```

returns 60